# Rellenar ComboBox desde código no muestra textos

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Dispongo de un ComboBox el cual relleno desde el constructor de la vista

```
<ComboBox Name="cbPuestos" DisplayMemberPath="NombreTipo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="640" FontSize="15" Height="63"/>
```

Para construirlo obtengo los puestos desde una clase que me devuelve un `List<Model>` y lo transformo a un diccionario de la siguiente manera:

```
//Clase con la obtención de datos
public SvcConfiguracion _svcConfiguracion;
public IDictionary dictPuestos = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public CambiarPuesto()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    _svcConfiguracion = new SvcConfiguracion();

    var puestos = _svcConfiguracion.GetPuestos();

    foreach (var puesto in puestos)
    {
        if (puesto.IP != null)
        {
            dictPuestos.Add(puesto.IP, puesto.Descripcion);
        }               
    }
    cbPuestos.ItemsSource = dictPuestos;
}
```

Al depurar me muestra el combo con muchos elementos pero en blanco.

[image: Muestra problema]

> **¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se encontraba en `DisplayMemberPath="NombreTipo"`, al ser un diccionario la manera correcta es:

```
DisplayMemberPath= "Value"
```

También puedes ahorrar el diccionario añadiendo el `List<Model>` directamente y apuntar con `DisplayMemberPath= "NombreElemento"` para mostrar el dato que deseas que sea el visible.